# how to get a part of requested data while subscribing a service method bringing data in angular2?

Tags: angular

I want to get only `'Month','data1' or 'data2' from`jsondata.json when requested. Here, service.ts bringing data and storing?
How to get a part of requested data while subscribing a service method bringing data?
How to achieve the desired result?

### jsondata.json

```
[{
        "Month": "Jan",
        "data1%": "58.2",
        "data2": "90.38",
        "data3": "87.4",
        "data4": "80.85"
    },
    {
        "Month": "feb",
        "data1%": "57.2",
        "data2": "90.38",
        "data3": "57.4",
        "data4": "85.85"
    }
]
```

### service.ts

```
gethpData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('assets/json/hfollder/jsondata.json')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body || [];
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    // alert('Server Error!');
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

### test.component.html

```
<button id='btn1' (click)='getdata('btn1')'>btn1</button>
<button id='btn2' (click)='getdata('btn2')'>btn2</button>
<button id='btn3' (click)='getdata('btn3')'>btn3</button>
<button id='btn4' (click)='getdata('btn4')'>btn4</button>
```

### test.component.ts

```
import { service } ....................// imported here
constructor(public jsonDataService: service){}

getdata(id){
if(id==='btn1'){
//get only 'month' data  from jsondata.json
monthdata =        //here store month data as ['Month','','',''....]

callmethod(monthdata);

}else if(id==='btn2'){
//get only 'data1' data  from jsondata.json
data1data =           //here store data1%  as ['dat1%','','',''....]


callmethod(data1data);
}
else if(id==='btn3'){
//get only 'data2' data  from jsondata.json
data2data =           //here store data2 data ['data2','','',''....]

callmethod(data2data);
}
}
callmethod(param1){
alert(param1);
}
```

Comment: In your Subscribe Response,you can loop through the JSON data and with the help of .(dot) operator you can get the desired data from your JSON response

Comment: Thanks, can you show it, so that i can understand properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array.map to get only the part of data you need:

```js
getdata = (id) => {
    this.jsonDataService.gethpData().subscribe(res => this.getPartOfData(id, res));
}

getPartOfData(id, res) {
    switch (id) { 
        case 'btn1':
            this.monthdata  = res.map(el => ({ Month: el.Month }));
            break;   
        case 'btn2':
            this.data1data  = res.map(el => ({ data1: el.data1 }));
            break;   
        case 'btn3':
            this.data2data  = res.map(el => ({ data2: el.data2 }));
            break;   
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error at- this.jsonDataService().subscribe(res => this.getPartOfData(id, res));

Comment: It's may be a problem of context of 'this'. I changed to use arrow function for getdata.

Comment: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Getting error at -this.jsonDataService()

Comment: Typo:change this.jsonDataService() to this.jsonDataService.gethpData()

Comment: Thanks, faly...One more issue, there is "data1%" in jsondata.json. How to get that.

Comment: Second, I want the month data as ['Month', ' ' , ' ' ,...........................] , where , empty strings are data .

Comment: To get "data1%", you do  res.map(el => ({ data1: el["data1%"] })). To get a list of month, it should be: this.monthdata  = res.map(el => el.Month);

Comment: Perhaps, I should generate a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, fully dynamic :

> test.component.html

```
<button id='btn1' (click)='getdata('Month')'>btn1</button>
<button id='btn1' (click)='getdata('data1%')'>btn1</button>
<button id='btn1' (click)='getdata('data2')'>btn1</button>
```

> test.component.ts

```
receivedData = {};

getdata(key){
    this.jsonDataService.gethpData(key).subscribe(data => {
        receivedData[key] = data;
        console.log(receivedData); // check this you will get idea
    });
}
```

> service.ts

```
gethpData(key): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('assets/json/hfollder/jsondata.json')
        .map(respData => {

            let extractedData = this.extractData(respData);
            // ---------- Logic ---------------
            if(key !== '' && extractedData.length > 0) {
                return extractedData.map(data => {
                    let map_data = {};
                    map_data[key] = data[key];
                    return map_data;
                })
            }
            return extractedData;
            // ---------- Logic ---------------

        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: getting error at -.map(data =>  ie ,Property 'map' does not exist on type '(res: Response) => any'.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr, it not about what is easy to implement, it depends on what is more dynamic and reliable

Answer (score 0):

Give a Try Like This

Create a object for your service in your component constructor like below

```
Constructor(private service : (Your Http Service Class Name))
```

in your Component

```
getdata(id){
let monthdata : any;
if(id==='btn1')
{
this.service.gethpData().subscribe(res=>
if(res!=null{
res.forEach(element => {  
monthdata =  element.Month;
  })
console.log(monthdata);
}
}
}
```